# VM Server goes shutdown automatically after every one Hour in ESXi Host

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2019, unexpected-shutdown

My Host server is ESXi where I have three virtual servers. These virtual servers automatically  shuts down continuously after one hour.

Comment: Are they Windows Server machines?

Answer (score 3):

If these are Windows Server machines, shutting down every hour is a typical behavior of trial licenses (which you shouldn't use in production) when not connected to the Internet. You can confirm this by looking at the Event Logs.

If they are Linux or Unix servers (or properly licensed Windows machines), look at scheduled tasks inside the guest:

- Linux/Unix: cron, systemctl, at, ps auxwwf| grep nohup
- Windows: Get-ScheduledTask

If you can rule out scheduled tasks or license issues, you should look at the hypervisor itself and possible PSU issues.

Comment: Yes, these windows Server (2019) are still in trail Version. You means due to trail version it goes shutdown???

Comment: @user785879 yes.

Comment: http://muliantophang.blogspot.com/2017/09/windows-server-evaluation-auto-shutdown.html might be a work around, but if 3 Month of testing for a windows server is not enough then you using it like a [warez software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warez) ;)